# Extended SimpleCursorAdapter overrided bindView works well on emulator but not on phone?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I extended SimpleCursorAdapter to change the row background color when an item is selected.

```
public class MyCursorAdaptor extends SimpleCursorAdapter 
{
    int SelectedItemPosition = -1;

    public MyCursorAdaptor(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) 
    {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
  }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) 
    {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        // SelectedItemPosition value is set from onclick event
        if (cursor.getPosition() == SelectedItemPosition)
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        else
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

It works well on emulator and my android tablet but not on my android phone. All items are being displayed correctly but the background color will not change when an item is selected. Then i found that actually bindView does not gets triggered at all on my phone!? How is that possible!?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found that actually bindView were called on my tablet and emulator every time i click on the listview but on my phone bindView only being called when i scroll the listview.